# How to align spaced text in the same line, but vertically? (Symbol list, Word 2010)

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm trying to align all of the definitions in a symbol list in word 2010. Now they all look like this

[image]

Anyone knows how to do this? I wanna align the definitions as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put that text in a table. with two rows.

First row will have only one column, and second row will have two columns.

First row is for the top line, and second row for symbols and definitions.

First column of second row are symbols, and second column of second row are definitions.

You can then left align the definitions in second column, so that their first letters are aligned.

You can also use a separate row for each symbol-definition line

Comment: But that process creates a lot of trouble, i can only fill the second column after i get the first one filled.   Also, I'm not able to define 2 columns in a single row, I can only define 2 columns for a whole page, I'm doing this in "Page Layout". How can I do it?

Comment: Ah! Got it, its a table! :D